# Running XC UI tests in parallel on device

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, ios-ui-automation, xcode10

From Xcode10 onwards we are able to run UI tests in parallel on multiple simulators.
However, I could not find a way to run on multiple devices. Is that not possible?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but from command line only. Alternative way - setup bot (Xcode -> Preferences -> Server & Bots). You will find all necessary settings for this.

Comment: xcodebuild test -scheme MyProjUITests -destination 'platform=iOS,name=First Personal device' -destination 'platform=iOS,name=Second personal device' -configuration "Debug" -parallel-testing-enabled YES

Comment: I went through the apple documentation. We are able to run on multiple devices using the above, however it repeats all the tests on both devices. But when we run  parallel on simulators, it splits the test cases between all the simulators.